# Draw path on MKMapView/Google map for building or parking place

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview, mapkit

Currently i am working on iOS project in which i have to draw path for building or parking place annotation, may be multi-level parking or basement parking.

Enable to find solution in google map or MKMapView.

Can anybody who are familiar with such issue help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Polyline drawing in Third dimension is not introduced in apple maps/google maps

Comment: OK, but without Third dimension if i want to draw path in building for two dimension only. how can i show path in building.

Comment: Update sentence formation

Comment: I don't think you can zoom in enough with MKMapView to do that. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ might be able to help with what you're trying to do.